# How to read the Android Device IMEI on a SOTI managed device?

Tags: android, imei, soti, mobicontrol

We are using [Soti Mobicontrol](https://soti.net/solutions/enterprise-mobility-management/) Managed Android devices in production and since [the IMEI access has been restricted after Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes) I was wondering if Soti agent which has access to the [Android Enterprise](https://www.android.com/enterprise/) features can provide us the IMEI so we use it as the device unique ID.

By the way, the company owns the devices and I don't believe it is a user privacy violation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a blurry and incomplete answer in the [Soti Discussion Forum](https://discussions.soti.net/thread/read_privileged_phone_state-permission-on-android-10/) and after many testing finally, I managed to make it work!!!

When you create an installation package for an Android APK file using the MobiControl *Package Studio* tool, you can contain Post-Install [Soti Scripts](https://soti.net/mc/help/v14.1/en/scriptcmds/reference/androidplus.html) that will run after installation is done:

[image]

One of the scripts is [`sendintent`](https://www.soti.net/mc/help/v14.2/en/scriptcmds/reference/sendintent.html?hl=sendintent) and, on the other hand, you also have access to some [macros](https://www.soti.net/mc/help/v14.2/en/console/other/macros.html) to get the device information namely %IMEI%, or %DEVICENAME% (which is not listed on the macro documentation!).

It means by defining a script like this you can have a Broadcast Message intent containing the IMEI and Device Name on Soti Managed Devices!

```
sendintent -b "intent:#Intent;action=com.mohsenoid.android.imei.ACTION;S.imei=%IMEI%;S.devicename=%DEVICENAME%;component=com.mohsenoid.android.imei/.ImeiReceiver;end;"
```

This script acts exactly the same as this ADB Shell command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.mohsenoid.android.imei.ACTION --es imei "SOME\ IMEI" --es devicename "SOME\ DEVICE\ NAME" -n com.mohsenoid.android.imei/.ImeiReceiver
```

The `BroadcastReceiver` inside your app can look something like this:

```
class ImeiReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        context ?: return
        intent ?: return

        val imei = intent.getStringExtra(IMEI_KEY) ?: return
        val deviceName = intent.getStringExtra(DEVICE_NAME_KEY) ?: return

        AppSettings.setValue(context, IMEI_KEY, imei)
        AppSettings.setValue(context, DEVICE_NAME_KEY, deviceName)

        Toast.makeText(context, "Received: IMEI: $imei - DeviceName: $deviceName", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    companion object {
        const val IMEI_KEY = "imei"
        const val DEVICE_NAME_KEY = "devicename"
    }
}
```

Do not forget that you also need to add the Broadcast Receiver to your AndroidManifest file with a proper intent filter and action.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".ImeiReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mohsenoid.android.imei.ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This GitHub repository holds a test app that can be used for this purpose:
https://github.com/mohsenoid/SOTI-IMEI

I hope this answer helps anyone who is using this service.